# Joomla Mobile app with offline access

Tags: html, mobile, joomla, offline

Is anyone aware of a way to host a mobile-friendly Joomla site where the user's phone stores an offline copy.

The site will be an information base / userguide and would be updated at every new release.

I would prefer not to repack and upload a new copy of the app every time there is a change made, hence why I've decided to make a Joomla site.

Comment: so the user downloads an entire copy of the site to their phone?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a JSON or XML feed from your Joomla site and then use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com) to create an app which checks the feed for new items on open.